# Is "Possible Duplicate" a death sentence?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A little while ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080514/c-sharp-wpf-full-control-over-gui-during-long-calculation) about a common issue involving WPF, threading, and background workers. Immediately it had received several comments and a proposed answer. It also received a "possible duplicate" warning and a downvote. However, soon afterward, the views came to a halt. It went from about 40 views in the first hour to 49 views in the 4 hours to follow. There were no more comments after the initial burst. After I saw the duplicate comment I explained how the answer provided in the question duplicated would not work for my situation, and edited my original question to be a bit more clear. Nonetheless, the "possible duplicate" vote still marks the question as a (possible) duplicate, and people pass the question by thinking it's answered.

How does one get a question answered if the solution isn't known in one in the duplicates, and people ignore the possible duplicate?

Comment: The reduced amount of views is probably more related to the question being pushed off of the relevant tags' page, than it is to the close-as-dupe suggestion. 7 hours is a heck of a long time for questions on SO. (Even though you posted it only 5 hours ago)

Comment: @Cerbrus The edit should have pushed it back to the front.

Comment: @sashoalm: Not when watching the ["Newest" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

Comment: The possible duplicate comment is just a comment to other visitors. It is not shown on the question list. People are not looking at the question either because the question isn't visible to them anymore (aged of the tag page) or because the title and summary do not attract them.

Comment: @Cebrus Sorry, my time guestimation skills are terrible. I'll fix that.

Comment: @einsteinsci don't use "Edit" markers and just add to your question to fix it.  Actually fix your question.  If people have misunderstood, rewrite as much as is necessary to clarify (even if it means rewriting the whole question).  As it stands now, you still have the original question and then a giant wall of text under an "Edit" marker.  No one is going to even read your edit because it is nothing but a wall of text.  (Just when rewriting, only clarify, don't change the question, especially when you have answers - you don't want to invalidate existing answers)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054592/first-day-first-day-of-this-month) was closed for being a duplicate, but I voted for reopening and explained why this was a different problem than the possible duplicate. It got reopened and the discussion went on.

Comment: *the "possible duplicate" vote still marks the question as a (possible) duplicate, and people pass the question by thinking it's answered* That sounds like jumping to conclusions (or mind reading).

Comment: Why not flag the comment as "no longer needed"?

Answer (score 5):

No it isn't, but the only way to prevent that kind of thing is to respond to such comments very shortly.

When you ask a question, you can't just go grab a beer or something, you must follow it in the following minutes to be able to respond to comments. Nothing annoys commenters most than a non-responsive OP.

That also applies to "possible duplicate of...". If you do nothing, some gold badge user will probably hammer & close it.

You have to "defend" your question with a comment, pining the person who proposed the duplicate, and also *edit* your question as the banner suggests (other users often defend the question if it was clearly wrongly flagged)

If your arguments are convincing, the people reading your comments & the person which flagged/voted to close will retract the close vote (same applies when a question is hammered, you can still ping the user who hammered/closed)

Also note that the "this question has already an answer here" banner is visible only to you until it's closed. Others just see a "possible duplicate of ..." comment, so it's not visually as imposing.

For me, the issue is often the other way round: a lot of potential answerers quickly answer, ignoring the "Possible duplicate of" comment, just to get easy rep just before it's closed...

The downvote is sometimes a side-effect of the "roomba" system: if the question is downvoted & closed as a duplicate without answer, it will be deleted automatically, so some people vote to close/downvote and move on. If your question is good you'll even get "corrective" upvotes.

So if the proposed answer answers (which can happen, actually!), then just close it yourself (will be marked "closed by Community")

If it doesn't:

- stay connected to respond to comments
- edit your question & ping the people who voted to close as duplicate
- It's tempting but *don't repost* another similar question, as you're liable to another close, more downvotes & possibly a moderator flag.

If your question is closed, editing it puts it in the reopen queue, so it can be reopened if the edit is substantial.

Answer (score -29):

I'd ask it again.

The questions marked as duplicates quickly fall into the depths in a site as ridiculously large as this one, and I personally skip the duplicates and follow links to the original question. The reason for that is that I know the 'first' question on the topic will have received the most attention and will (in most cases) be the most help.

If the question has changed and you're now confident it's not a duplicate of another question, asking the question again will remove the vote. It will also give the question those precious few moments at the top of the 'newest' list.

Comment: Wonderful way to get question-banned in a hurry, and leaving lots of garbage behind. Anyway, the new question will probably summarily be marked as a self-duplicate.

Comment: I don't understand though... He said it wasn't a duplicate, so if it were marked that way again it would be in error.

Comment: You are advocating re-asking his question to get rid of the duplicate-flags and votes. How is that re-asked question not a duplicate of his original question? And are you aware that one can clarify the original question so it obviously isn't a duplicate if you were not clear enough, even if you failed to do so early enough to avoid getting closed? In which case it sends the question to the re-open queue, and if you actually did it, it will be re-opened fast.

Comment: But it is a death sentence...
Kanye West has no chance of saving his career because he is already labelled. No edit will ever just remove any negative tags on it and get answered. That's why there are 2,000,000 abandoned questions on this site - they are labelled as bad, and when they're improved they're overlooked. Starting afresh and letting the old question be deleted seems like a much faster way to get the question answered.

Comment: As much as there are flaws with flagging questions, I don't think that reposting will cause anything but more problems. As @Deduplicator (relevantly named) mentioned, reposting is a duplicate of the first attempt. Nonetheless it is quite reasonable for questions to be overlooked when tagged as "possible duplicate", even if it is done in error.